# C#: Marshall array of structs with strings from C++/ObjectiveC in Unity to C#

Tags: c#, c++, objective-c, unity-game-engine, marshalling

I'm trying to Marshall ObjectiveC/C++ created array of structs with strings into C# and I haven't succeed. Most of the time C# marshalling can't find the "value" string field. This is the best I've got so far:

C# struct:

```
private struct Entry
{
    public string Key;
    public string Value;
}
```

C# code

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Convert()
{
    var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    getEntries(NativeInstance, out IntPtr pUnmanagedStringArray, out int keysCount);

    IntPtr[] pIntPtrArray = new IntPtr[keysCount];
    Entry[] entriesInDictionary = new Entry[keysCount];

    // I'm not really sure I've done this correctly?
    Marshal.Copy(pUnmanagedStringArray, pIntPtrArray, 0, keysCount);

    for (int i = 0; i < keysCount; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log("Iter " + i);

        // I'm not really sure I've done this correctly?
        entriesInDictionary[i] = Marshal.PtrToStructure<Entry>(pIntPtrArray[i]);
    }

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pUnmanagedStringArray); // Free native malloc for array

    foreach (var entry in entriesInDictionary)
    {
        Debug.Log("Entry" + entry.Key);
        Debug.Log("Value" + entry.Value);

        //dic.Add(entry.key, entry.value);
    }

    return dic;
}
```

C++/ObjectiveC

```
struct Entry {
    const char* key;
    const char* value;
};

void getEntries(NSDictionary* dictionary, const Entry* &_entries, int &size) {
    int count = (int) [dictionary count];

    Entry* entries = (Entry*) malloc(count * sizeof(Entry) );

    int i = 0;
    for(id key in dictionary) {
        id value = [dictionary objectForKey:key];

        entries[i].key = Utils::mallocCharStr(key); // malloc char* from NSString.
        entries[i].value = Utils::mallocCharStr(value); // malloc char* from NSString.

        ++i;
    }

    _entries = entries;
    size = count;
}
```

I'm very lost at this point and I've tried different combinations. Also I've tried a struct of IntPtr for both strings but then I know for certain that the "value" pointer is 0.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your unity version?

Comment: Latest. So 2019.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue. My problem is how I create/read the array of structs. In the original C# implementation it was expected than the given array was an array of pointers to structs, but the native code created an array with the structs themselves.

The problem can be solved with two different approaches. Updating the C++ code to create an array of pointers to structs:

```
void getEntries(NSDictionary* dictionary, Entry** &_entries, int &size) {
    int count = (int) [dictionary count];

    // Array of pointers! Structs will be malloc-ed individually on the loop.
    Entry** entries = (Entry**) malloc(count * sizeof(Entry*) );

    int i = 0;
    for(id key in dictionary) {
        id value = [dictionary objectForKey:key];

        // It creates a pointer to the struct
        entries[i] = (Entry*) malloc(sizeof(Entry));

        entries[i]->key = Utils::mallocCharStr(key);
        entries[i]->value = Utils::mallocCharStr(value);

        ++i;
    }

    _entries = entries;
    size = count;
}
```

And the way C# would process would be:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Convert()
{
    var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    getEntries(NativeInstance, out IntPtr pUnmanagedArray, out int keysCount);

    IntPtr[] pIntPtrArray = new IntPtr[keysCount];

    // This was the original problem.
    // Now it copies the native array pointers to individual IntPtr. Which now they point to individual structs.
    Marshal.Copy(pUnmanagedArray, pIntPtrArray, 0, keysCount);

    for (int i = 0; i < keysCount; i++)
    {
        Entry entry = Marshal.PtrToStructure<Entry>(pIntPtrArray[i]); // Magic!
        dic.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pIntPtrArray[i]); // Free the individual struct malloc
    }

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pUnmanagedArray); // Free native array of pointers malloc.

    return dic;
}
```

==

The other possible solution is to keep the C++ the way it was on the original question. So it means the native code creates an array of structs (not pointers). But then C# code need to be updated **to correctly offset every item in the array**.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Convert()
{
    var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    getEntries(NativeInstance, out IntPtr pUnmanagedArray, out int keysCount);

    // Note that we don't use Marshal.Copy(...).
    // Every item in the array has an memory offset of the size of the struct, rather than the size of the pointer to a struct.

    for (int i = 0; i < keysCount; i++)
    {
        // "Selects" the nth structure by offseting the original pointer element:
        IntPtr pCurrent = pUnmanagedArray + i * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Entry));

        Entry entry = Marshal.PtrToStructure<Entry>(pCurrent);

        dic.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
    }

    // It only frees the array of struct itself because it contains the structs themselves.
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pUnmanagedArray);

    return dic;
}
```

Note that the struct's strings are automatically freed when doing the automagic marshaling.

Comment: I wonder if there's an alternative of Marshal.Copy() to create an array of a given offset rather than the default pointers size.